# Eclipse - How to get all preferences for a specific JFace preference page

Tags: java, eclipse, jface

I'm working on trying to create some preference pages using the JFace PreferencePage class. I've created two separate pages that use the same store but am having trouble getting the preferences for the individual pages.

In the following segment of code I create my preference manager, store and launch the dialog.

```
private void launchPrefsDialog(final Composite parent) throws IOException
{
  PreferenceManager manager = new PreferenceManager();
  PreferenceStore store = new PreferenceStore(UI_PREFERENCES_ID);

  // Load the preferences
  try
  {
     store.load();
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
     Logger.logWarning(TAG, e.getMessage());
  }

  // Add the language preferences to the preferences manager
  PreferenceNode languagePreferences = new PreferenceNode("Languages", new LanguagePreferencePage(parent));
  PreferenceNode ignoreDirPreferences = new PreferenceNode(IGNORE_DIRECTORIES_PREFERENCE_PAGE_ID, new IgnoredDirectoriesPreferencePage(parent));
  manager.addToRoot(languagePreferences);
  manager.addToRoot(ignoreDirPreferences);

  // Create a new preference dialog and load in the preference file
  PreferenceDialog dialog = new PreferenceDialog(null, manager);
  dialog.setPreferenceStore(store);

  // Open the dialog
  int returnCode = dialog.open();

  if (returnCode == Window.OK)
  {
     save(returnCode, store);
  }

}
```

The in the pages I'm I can actually get the individual preferences I've added, but I want to get a list of the preferences for the page. I've been trying to use the IpreferenceStore but really don't know what I should be doing. Any help would be great.

```
IPreferenceStore store = getPreferenceStore();
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to list all the preference values. Preference pages normally use known key values.

Comment: Well If the preference page is initially empty and I add three items, how do I get the three items in another class from that page. When I open that preference page again, how does the preference page retrieve those three values?

Comment: Like how does the PreferencePage know the values which belong to it.

Comment: Preference pages use hard coded key values. You call `store.getString("known key")` and `store.setValue("known key", value)`

Comment: So the known values will have to stored elsewhere I take it, like in a list or something. I've really found these preferences hard to get my head around. When working with Android it seems much more straight forward dealing with preferences.